# Cannot inject custom bean for Spring Security Authentication interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use Spring dependency injection to inject the `Authentication` from Spring Security into the Spring components.
I have a bean definition of type `Authentication`, but when Spring tries to inject the `Authentication` bean into a controller, it fails saying

`"No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.Authentication' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"`

I am using Spring 5.3.7 and Spring Security 5.5.0.

#### Bean definition in `AuthenticationConfig.java`

```
package com.mydomain.authentication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfig {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("defaultAuthentication")
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }
}
```

#### Bean injection in `Controller.java`

```
package com.mydomain.authentication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/resource")
public class Controller {

    private final Authentication authentication;

    @Autowired
    public Controller( // <-- HERE THE INJECTION FAILS
            @Qualifier("defaultAuthentication") final Authentication authentication
    ) {
        this.authentication = authentication;
    }
}
```

I also tried the same code without `@Qualifier` with same negative result.

If I replace `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` with a custom simplistic interface `Authentication`, the dependency on that interface gets injected!

#### Dummy interface to test DI `Authentication.java`

```
public interface Authentication {}
```

#### Bean definition in `AuthenticationConfiguration.java` with custom interface type

Replacing the `getAuthentication()` method above with the following code:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("defaultAuthentication")
public Authentication getAuthentication() { // <-- Authentication = custom interface
    return new Authentication(){};
}
```

#### UPDATE: injection of a custom proxy

Based on the comment of Daniel Wosch I have created a custom implementation of the `Authentication` interface that wraps the `Authentication` from the `ContextHolder` and delegates the calls to it.

The injection works, but is it safe in terms of security?

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import java.util.Collection;

public class AuthenticationProxy implements Authentication {

    private Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return this.getAuthentication().getCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return this.getAuthentication().getDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return this.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return this.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean b) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.getAuthentication().setAuthenticated(b);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getAuthentication().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this at all. Remove your `@Bean` and your `@Qualifier`, and everything should Just Work automatically.

Comment: I am wondering if it makes sense this way. You are trying to inject a Bean which returns an object from an static method call which is bound to the current user. I think you need to wrap the call in an own Class / Interface and then inject that Interface / class as dependency. This class has a method getAuthentication which calls the static method.

Comment: @DanielWosch I have updated and modified my question according to your comment

Comment: You can also just define your own interface e.g. `IAuthenticationProxy` Or better `IAuthFacade` with one method `getAuthentication`. In the implementing class getAuthentication returns the result of the static method call to SecurityContextHolder. This way you don’t need to implement all other methods from authentication class.

Comment: But if you just need the Authentication object in your controller level you can also just define Authentication as method parameter of your controller method without any other annotations and you’ll be fine. Just define it as bean if you need it on other layers than the Controller layer